# on key-up text field to search database, then retrieve data on other text field

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, autocomplete, onkeyup

Please help me! I want to live search (on key-up) by enter customer phone number then it will retrieve customer name and email from database.[Here my example form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB9oo.png)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

      $(function(){
          $(".cust_phone").keyup(function() {
          var cust_name = $(this).val();
          var cust_email = $(this).val();
          var dataString = 'cust_phone='+cust_name+cust_email;
          if(cust_name!='' && cust_email!='') {
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "customer_info.php",
              data: dataString,
              cache: false,
              success: function(html) {
                var data = html.split['|'];
                var cust_phone = data[0];
                var cust_name = data[1];
                var cust_email = data[2];
                $("#cust_phone").val(cust_phone);
                $("#cust_name").val(cust_name);
                $("#cust_email").val(cust_email);
              }
            });
          }
          return false;
        });

</script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="text" name="cust_phone" id="cust_phone">
  <input type="text" name="cust_name" id="cust_name">
  <input type="text" name="cust_email" id="cust_email">

</body>
</html>
```

This is first file (cutomer_form.php)

```
<?php

$cust_phone= $_POST['cust_phone'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT cust_phone
  FROM rent WHERE cust_phone LIKE '$search'");

// $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT cust_phone
//   FROM rent WHERE cust_phone = '$search'");

$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$cust_name = $data['cust_name'];
$cust_phone = $data['cust_phone'];
$cust_email = $data['cust_email'];

echo $cust_phone .'|'. $cust_name.'|'.$cust_email;

?>
```

This is second file (customer_info.php)

Comment: Can reply in full code if my code had many mistake. I am a student who wants to learn more. Your contribution is appreciated! :)

Comment: Okay... Now, does this work? Or are you getting any errors?

Comment: Not work, can you help me to fix it in full detail of code. If i write wrong code.Please fix my error. I love to learn

Comment: First of all ***DO NOT USE `mysql`!*** That is completely outdated and thrown into the dumpster. instead, use [MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). And, I would suggest you to access `customer_info.php` via the web browser and see if you have any output there. If there is an error in your php script you can find it there. And what version of php are you using?

Comment: And also, add the error handler to `$.ajax`. You can do that by adding `, error:function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log(errorThrown) }` after `success` of your jQuery AJAX object. This will allow you to see if there are any errors, by accessing the console in web browser's developer tools.

Comment: I have change query into mysqli but  same result i get. No error i get but the output is not working customer_info.php